# Render a book using RMarkown files in different folders in Bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I want to create a bookdown book using RMarkdown files which are in different folders. I tried to achieve this by giving path of RMarkdown file which is in different folder in `_bookdown.yml` file like this:

```
rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", "02-literature.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd","C:/Users/sm/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/03-method.rmd"]
```

But, got this error:

> bookdown::render_book()Rendering book in directory '.'Error in check_special_chars(files) : Filenames must not contain special charactersIn addition: Warning message:In check_special_chars(files) : The filename "C:\Users\sm\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\bookdown\rstudio\templates\project\resources\03-method.rmd" contains special characters. You may rename it to, e.g., "C--Users-sm-Documents-R-win-library-3.5-bookdown-rstudio-templates-project-resources-03-method.rmd".

When I tried to escape special character as shown in this link https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/special-chars.html like this:

```
rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", "02-literature.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd","C\:/Users/sm/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/bookdown/rstudio/templates/project/resources/03-method.rmd"]
```

I'm getting this error:

> bookdown::render_book()Rendering book in directory '.'Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : Scanner error: while parsing a quoted scalar at line 5, column 1 found unknown escape character at line 5, column 3

Is it possible to generate a bookdown book using RMarkdown files in different folders? If yes, am I going in the right direction or how to give path correctly of RMarkdown file which is in different folder in `_bookdown.yml` file.

Please help!

Comment: Even the official [Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://github.com/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook) doesn't generate the book from different folders. All files need to be in the Root directory, no child folders or other folders for Rmarkdown to render properly.

Comment: The most you can do is use Rmd's within sub-directories within your bookdown folder (as long as you have `new_session = FALSE`, as is the default, when running `bookdown::render_book`). [Source](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html#new-session).

Answer (score 0):

Include `rmd_subdir: yes` in `_bookdown.yml`.

> `rmd_subdir`: whether to search for book source Rmd files in
> subdirectories (by default, only the root directory is searched). This
> may be either a boolean (e.g. true will search for book source Rmd
> files in the project directory and all subdirectories) or list of
> paths if you want to search for book source Rmd files in a subset of
> subdirectories.